# Получить только одно совпадение строки

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Находим числа, после которых стоит "м".

```
$dlina = "420м 100г и 400м 100г";

$str_dlina = preg_match_all("/\d+\s(м)\b|\d+(м)\b|\d+\s(метров)\b|\d+(метров)\b/iu", $dlina, $out);
$dlina = implode(', ', $out[0]);
echo $dlina_result = preg_replace('/[^\d]/', '', $dlina);
```

В результате получаем "420 400" (т.е. функция находит два числа, после которых стоит "м").

А как получить только одно число, например, лишь первое совпадение? (тут 420)

Comment: `preg_match` ? Ты же сам явно `preg_match_all` указываешь на то, что - надо брать все совпадения.

Comment: @Eugene X просто preg_match выдаст ошибку implode(): Invalid arguments passed. Но и собрать изначально все значения тоже хотелось бы, а уже потом выбрать из них, какое именно оставить (первое или второе), если это возможно

Comment: Именно такое поведение и должно быть, ибо preg_match возвращает только первое совпадение.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

если нужно только первое совпадение, то используйте `preg_match` а не `preg_match_all`

```
if(preg_match('/(\d+)\s?(?=м(?>етров)?\b)/iu', $txt, $matches)){
    $result = $matches[1];
}
```

если нужны все, то оставляете `preg_match_all` и результат все также в `$matches[1]`

Comment: Спасибо, так получилось! Более простой пример оказался понятен и работает, поэтому отмечу как верный ответ.

Answer (score 1):

В твоём случае наверно вот такой результат ожидал?

`$matches[0]` после map первое совпадение, [1] второе и.т.д.

```php
<?php
$dlina = '420м 100г и 400м 100г';
$re = '/\d+м|\d+\sм|\d+\sметров|\d+метров/i';

# Получаем все совпадения в $matches[0]
if ( preg_match_all($re, $dlina, $matches) > 0 ) {
    # Фильтруем их и убираем м,метров
    # Прикол в чём, что intval обрубает знаки справа если это не спецсимволы
    # А пробел и "м" это не спецсимволы.
    $matches = array_map(fn($e) => intval($e), $matches[0]);
    # Собарем из массива [420, 400] строку
    $dlina = implode(", ", $matches);
    echo $dlina;
} else {
    echo "Nothing found...";
}
```

Comment: в результате ожидаю вывод только одного значения - либо 420 либо 400. В этом примере выводятся оба числа через запятую. А если поставить $matches[1] то получаем ошибки (Undefined offset: 1 ; array_map(): Expected parameter 2 to be an array, null given in ; implode(): Invalid arguments passed)

Comment: `$dlina = implode(", ", $matches);`   Собирает из массива строку разделённую запятыми.

`$matches` ПОСЛЕ `array_map` не перед...

Comment: $dlina = implode(", ", $matches)[0] ? Тогда он выводит только цифру "4". Если [1] то выводит "2" и пр. Либо я не понимаю как правильно нужно сделать, либо неправильно объяснил. Пожалуйста, можешь поправить пример, что бы он в echo $dlina; выдавал только одно число?

Comment: `$matches[0]` после `array_map` = `420`
`$matches[1]` = `400`

Comment: не выдает оно одно число. Ни в sandbox ни на рабочем проекте... http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/aaaae3c043ddf1e493d762d607454b891b334585

Comment: большое спасибо за ответы и вариант, но так и не получилось у меня вывести нужный результат. Не знаю, наверное я что то недопонял, хотя конкретно ваш вариант выдает у меня оба числа. Поэтому ответом отметил другой